# Mediawiki API: How do I list all subcategories of a category?

Tags: wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I am using the following wikimedia API to list all pages with a certain category: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers

E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Physics

However, the results returned are equivalent to the 'Pages' section and do not include those in the 'Subcategories', e.g., 'Concepts in physics', 'Subfields of physics‎', etc. Does anyone know how to retrieve subcategories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the documentation mentions, you need to add `cmtype=subcat` to your query:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Physics&cmtype=subcat